# How to modify source column in Copy Activity of Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from a csv file into a database table. I created a pipeline in Azure Data Factory and added a `Copy Activity`. I set the source and the destination datasets.

During the copy operation, I want to prefix the values of the column `Col1` in the source csv file with a fixed string. At the bottom of the `Mapping` section in the UI, there is an option such as "`Add dynamic content`". I guess I would be able to add an expression here for such a mapping but I could not find any information on how to do that.

What is the correct way of accomplishing this?

Comment: To perform most transformations like you're indicating you should instead run a derived column transformation in a data flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column.  Add dynamic content for the copy data operation is for things at the ADF level, like a parameter value, trigger start time, pipeline name, output of previous step, etc. - basically whatever the expression wizard tells you is available to query.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a dynamic column value in copy activity supports only the ADF parameter /function values which would be common for all rows.

As of now there is no direct support to modify a column at row by row level in copy activity.

[image]

You can do it via 2 ways:

1. use copy activity to copy into staging table and then use an SP activity to modify from staging table to final tables
2. use dataflow derived column transformation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column

Answer (score 1):

- As directed by **@Zorkolot** and **@Nandan**, copy data activity in general is to deal with moving files/folders from different sources to different sinks.
- Since the requirement is to add a fixed string prefix to an existing column, you need to use dataflows. Dataflows can help with manipulating/converting data as required.
- You can use derived column transformation as shown in the below. I have added `pre` string as a prefix to id column.

[image]

- Another way is to use one copy data activity and a script activity to copy to the database and write an update query with `concat` function on the required column with prefix with a query like this:

```
update t1 set <your_col>=concat('pre',<your_col>)
```

[image]

- Another way would be to use Python notebook to add the prefix to required column and then move it to database.